# Java8 and Spring Data Neo4j application queries

Tags: neo4j, spring-boot, java-8, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I have a bunch of questions regarding Java 8 and SDN4. I created a model in Neo4j v3.0, played a bit with Cypher queries, and now moved to creating a Spring Boot application. As i started coding classes in Java, I've begun to rethink some of my model as well. Here's some questions in my mind (and I haven't found an example explaining this):

1. Do you need to use Interfaces in Java, with SDN?For eg. I'd code a `Product` interface and then have my products implement it, but is that how it's done when working with labels?
2. This is somewhat tied to my question on inheritance - I'd usually have a `ProductFamily` that my `Product` would inherit from. At the database level its modeled as `(:Product)-[PartOf]->(:ProductFamily)`, but in the code these would not be super/sub class.
3. Any examples of using Generics in a graph context?
4. Is there a way to define constraints on what relationships a node can have and their direction in Java?

I understand there is probably not one right answer, but there's precious little on the web, so hope to get enlightened here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you had a Product interface annotated with `@NodeEntity`, then the you'll have the `Product` label in addition to the label on your implementing class, which I assume is what you want. If your interface isn't annotated, then your implementing classes will not inherit a label from it.
2. Not sure what you mean- if you say you have a `ProductFamily` that `Product` inherits from, but in the code it would not be a super/sub class?
   Based on your graph model, if you want `(:Product)-[PartOf]->(:ProductFamily)` then you will have a `Product` class that maintains a reference to a `ProductFamily` class, and that reference annotated with `@Relationship`. If the `Product` class inherits from `ProductFamily` then persisting the `Product` will result in two labels- `Product` and `ProductFamily` because a `Product` IS-A `ProductFamily`.
3. How do you see yourself using generics- the answer really depends on that. Some cases are supported, some are not (an example of something not supported right now is [equivalent of template.createRelationBetween in SDN4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32694961/equivalent-of-template-createrelationbetween-in-sdn4/32695905?noredirect=1#comment53410902_32695905))
4. Yes, via the `@Relationship` annotation which accepts a `type` and `direction`. Note that this annotation only constrains your domain model, but you could very well flout this by creating relationships in another direction via a custom query.

Comment: Thank you! Re (2) and (3), the idea is that I could work with ProductFamily based Collections as Generics even though i have Products returning in a query. And most properties are defined at `ProductFamily` class, with `Product` class having only properties specific to it. Eg. User queries for all `Product`s supporting a specific feature-i can then return `ProductFamily` if its a family-wide feature and some specific `Product`s when its not, but my collection is the same. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Yes, possible, though you'll have two labels on the Product nodes (Product and ProductFamily)